# Ajustar contenido al tamaño del contenedor

Tags: javascript

El objetivo es que el tamaño de cada div dentro del contenedor `container` sea dependiente a la cantidad de div que exista, **igual a los tabs de una navegador**

**El tamaño del contenido deberia variar**

es decir: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

posteo mi codigo:

```css
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div#container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
</div>
```

**Nota**:*no quiero usar nada de jquery*

Comment: No se entiende la pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que está mal en el snippet? ¿Cuál es el objetivo?

Comment: ¿Quieres que si el contenido no entra en el tamaño del div este desaparezca?

Comment: Aclara mejor porque en realidad no se entiende

Comment: Por que no intentas usar <table>...</table> en lugar de <div>

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas utilizar javascript, puedes solucionarlo tan solo con CSS, agregando a tus `divs` las siguientes propiedades:

```
white-space: nowrap;      //Mantener el texto en una sola linea
overflow: hidden;         //Si el texto no entra en su contenedor se oculta
```

Adicionalmente puedes agregar la manera en que va a truncar el text, según [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

`text-overflow: ellipsis`, por ejemplo agrega puntos suspensivos (...) solo funciona cuando se seteó el width en píxeles (no funciona con %).

```css
div{
  width: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: red;
 
}
```

```html
<div> Hola mundo </div>
<div> Hola </div>
<div> Ho </div>
```

En tu caso, si quieres simplemente truncar al tamaño del div contenedor utilizas `text-overflow: clip`

```css
div#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div#container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;      
  overflow: hidden;         
  text-overflow: clip;  
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola</div>
  <div>h</div>
</div>
```

Comment: porque desaparecio el scroll?

Answer (score 0):

Complementando un poco lo ya dicho por **@Marcos Martínez**, con `CSS` lo puedes lograr, Ejemplo:

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div.container>div {
  background-color: orange;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
  <div>hola mundo</div>
</div>
```